Single millisecond send resolution with python-can, Vector CANalyzer
python version: 3.9.13, python-can version: 4.0.0
I am trying to send a CAN message every millisecond using python-can to access Vector's CANalyzer software. Using the code below, I would expect to see a message every millisecond:
import can
import time
import logging

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype="vector", channel=0, bitrate=500000, app_name='CANalyzer')

def periodic_send(msg, bus):
    task = bus.send_periodic(msg, 0.001)
    assert isinstance(task, can.CyclicSendTaskABC)

    return task

tasks = []

msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xCE, data=[1, 1, 1, 1], is_extended_id=False)
tasks.append(periodic_send(msg,bus))

time.sleep(200)

However, when I look at the signal in CANalyzer, it shows the message being sent every 15ms or so (blue measurement cursor is first sample, orange is second):

I have also tried managing timing directly and have similarly been unable to achieve single millisecond intervals:
import can
import time

class PreciseTimer():
    def __init__(self, task_function, period):
        self.task_function = task_function
        self.period = period
        self.i = 0
        self.t0 = time.perf_counter()

    def sleep(self):
        self.i += 1
        delta = self.t0 + self.period * self.i - time.perf_counter()
        if delta > 0:
            time.sleep(delta)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.task_function()
            self.sleep()

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype="vector", channel=0, bitrate=500000, app_name='CANalyzer')

def send_can_msg():
    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xCE, data=[1, 1, 1, 1], is_extended_id=False)
    bus.send(msg)

timer = PreciseTimer(send_can_msg, 0.001)
timer.run()

This is possible using an Interactive Generator in CANalyzer, but is it possible with python-can?
